# Node Identity Registration in Corda

Tags: corda

I have generated self signed keystore and certificate using keytool command, is there any way to register it as part of node's identity.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The keystore and certificates are generated automatically when running the nodes in dev mode. You do this by adding the following line to each node's `node.conf` file:

```
devMode : true
```

See https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html for more details.

Once the keystore and certificates have been generated, you can turn off dev mode if you want. You do this by stopping each node, setting `devMode : false`, and restarting each node.

Comment: I knew about devMode: false attribute, i have generated self signed keypair, certificate and truststore cacerts file, but it throws exception:       
E 11:55:16+0530 [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Identity certificate not found. Please eith
er copy your existing identity key and certificate from another node, or if you
don't have one yet, fill out the config file and run corda.jar --initial-registr
ation. Read more at: https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.validateKeystore

Comment: It throws exception while running java -jar corda.jar command where it find self signed certificate from certificate directory.

Comment: @ChintanKansara We've updated the docs on network permissioning to make the process clearer. Can you check https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html?